# Do i need to use ROSBRIDGE for controlling my robot from my PC?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using platform ubantu on PC and having ROS indigo on my robot. Now i want control it completely using PC and also want to see video taken by on board camera. Do i need to use ROSBRIDGE???  Without rosbridge is it possible to control the bot?
Thank you  in advance!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237348/do-i-need-to-use-rosbridge-for-controlling-my-robot-from-my-pc?/) by [swati shirke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27205/swati-shirke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. ROS handles distributed processing "out of the box" (in this case, ROS nodes both on the robot and on your PC). You need to read the basic documentation and gain a working understanding of ROS nodes, the ROS master, and pub/sub functionality (at a minimum). Try starting at the [ROS core components](http://www.ros.org/core-components/) page and go from there.

Also, directly (1st sentence) from the [rosbridge wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite): *Rosbridge provides a JSON API to ROS functionality for non-ROS programs.* Which is quite clearly not what you need.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2016-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think there are several ways to solve this situation, I guess the master is running in the robot, you can have ROS installed in your laptop and then connect to the master running in the robot to "control" it. If you use Rosbridge is mainly if you want to access the data through the internet (or network), could you be more specific in your question?, so people can give to you a better advice.

---

Originally posted by [pablocesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20992/pablocesar/) with karma: 252 on 2016-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1